# how to use trigger in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
CREATE TABLE table_001(
Day_date date
);

CREATE TABLE table_002(
new_Day_date date
);



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGERS trigger
AFTER INSERT ON table_001
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_002 VALUES(SYSDATE)
END;
```

Comment: I have been trying to run the above code. it gives "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors. It's **not**  "TRIGGERS". Also, give a valid trigger name. A semicolon was missing after the insert.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT ON table_001
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table_002(new_Day_date) VALUES(SYSDATE);
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT ON table_001
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_002 VALUES(SYSDATE);
END;
```